# What is the relationship between nr_events in io_setup and nr in io_submit and io_getevents?

Tags: c, linux, aio

```
   #include <linux/aio_abi.h>          /* Defines needed types */

   int io_setup(unsigned nr_events, io_context_t *ctx_idp);
   int io_submit(io_context_t ctx_id, long nr, struct iocb **iocbpp);
   int io_getevents(io_context_t ctx_id, long min_nr, long nr,
                    struct io_event *events, struct timespec *timeout);
```

Question 1:

If I use `io_setup(32, ctx_idp)`, can I submit 100 times? Or I can only submit 32 times and use io_getevents to handle the data first, then do the submit again?

```
io_submit(ctx_id, 100, iocbpp);
```

or

```
for(I = 0; I<100; I++) {
    io_submit(ctx_id, 1, iocbpp);
}
```

Question 2:

Is `long min_nr, long nr` in io_getevents decided by nr_events in io_setup?

```
1 <= min_nr <= 32 and 1 <= nr <= 32?
```

Or decided by `nr` in io_submit? so

```
1 <= min_nr <= 100 and 1 <= nr <= 100?
```

Comment: aio is a legacy interface, you may like to have a look at [`liburing`](https://github.com/axboe/liburing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer to question 1:

Yes you can create a context to process 32 *concurrent* requests with `io_setup` and run `io_submit` for 100 requests with something similar to `io_submit(ctx_id, 100, iocbpp);`. I have tested successfully this on CentOS 7 (without `libaio` using adapted code from [here](https://oxnz.github.io/2016/10/13/linux-aio/)).

Answer to question 2:

`io_getevents` parameters are related to number of requests submitted with `io_submit` (I have also successfully tested this).

Here is the code that I have used.
It takes 2 parameters and allows to to write to a single file but at different offsets to that you can check what `io_submit` is writing.

```
/*
 * taio.c
 * 
 * test AIO on Linux
 * 
 * taio <number of operations for io_setup> <number of control blocks for io_submit>
 *
 *
 */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <linux/aio_abi.h>



inline int io_setup(unsigned nr, aio_context_t *ctxp) {
    return syscall(__NR_io_setup, nr, ctxp);
}

inline int io_destroy(aio_context_t ctx) {
    return syscall(__NR_io_destroy, ctx);
}

inline int io_submit(aio_context_t ctx, long nr, struct iocb **iocbpp) {
    return syscall(__NR_io_submit, ctx, nr, iocbpp);
}

inline int io_getevents(aio_context_t ctx, long min_nr, long max_nr,
        struct io_event *events, struct timespec *timeout) {
    return syscall(__NR_io_getevents, ctx, min_nr, max_nr, events, timeout);
}

/*
 * size must match
 */
#define IO_SIZE 10 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    aio_context_t ctx;
    struct iocb *tcb;
    struct iocb **lcb;
    char *data;
    char **tdata;
    struct io_event *events;
    int ret;
    int fd;
        int i,j;
    long int nr_iosetup;
    long int nr_iosubmit;
    int current_offset;

    if (argc != 1 && argc != 3)
    {
        printf("taio: usage <number of operations for io_setup> <number of control blocks for io_submit>");
        return 1;
    }

    nr_iosetup = 1;
    nr_iosubmit = 1;
    for(i=0; i < argc; i++)
    {
        if (i == 1)
            nr_iosetup = atoi(argv[1]);
        if (i == 2)
            nr_iosubmit = atoi(argv[2]);
    }

    tdata = malloc(nr_iosubmit * sizeof(char *));
    if (tdata == NULL)  
    {
        perror("malloc tdata");
        return 1;
    }

    tcb = malloc(nr_iosubmit * sizeof(struct iocb));
    if (tcb == NULL)    
    {
        perror("malloc tcb");
        return 1;
    }

    lcb = malloc(nr_iosubmit * sizeof(struct iocb *));
    if (lcb == NULL)    
    {
        perror("malloc lcb");
        return 1;
    }

    for (j=0; j < nr_iosubmit; j++)
    {
        data = malloc(IO_SIZE);
        if (data == NULL)
        {
            perror("malloc data");
            return 1;
        }
        tdata[j] = data;
        sprintf(data, "%d\n", j);
    }

    events = malloc(nr_iosubmit * sizeof(struct io_event));
    if (events == NULL) 
    {
        perror("malloc events");
        return 1;
    }


    ret = unlink("/tmp/taio.dat");
    /* ignore error */

    fd = open("/tmp/taio.dat", O_RDWR | O_CREAT | O_EXCL,  S_IRWXU);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("open\t\t=> fd=%d\n", fd);

    ctx = (aio_context_t)0;
    ret = io_setup(nr_iosetup, &ctx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_setup");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("io_setup\t=> nr_iosetup=%ld ret=%d\n", nr_iosetup, ret);


    /* command-specific options */
    for (j=0, current_offset=0; j < nr_iosubmit; j++)
    {
            /* setup I/O control block */
        memset(&tcb[j], 0, sizeof(struct iocb));
        tcb[j].aio_fildes = fd;
        tcb[j].aio_lio_opcode = IOCB_CMD_PWRITE;
        tcb[j].aio_buf = (uint64_t)tdata[j];
        tcb[j].aio_offset = current_offset;
        tcb[j].aio_nbytes = IO_SIZE;

        lcb[j] = &tcb[j];

        current_offset += IO_SIZE;
    }

    ret = io_submit(ctx, nr_iosubmit, lcb);
    if (ret < 0) 
    {
        perror("io_submit");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("io_submit\t=> nr_iosubmit=%ld ret=%d\n", nr_iosubmit, ret);

    ret = io_getevents(ctx, nr_iosubmit, nr_iosubmit, events, NULL);
    printf("io_getevents\t=> ret=%d\n", ret);

    ret = io_destroy(ctx);
    if (ret < 0) {
        perror("io_destroy");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("io_destroy\t=> ret=%d\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

Execution:

```
./taio 32 100
open            => fd=3
io_setup        => nr_iosetup=32 ret=0
io_submit       => nr_iosubmit=100 ret=100
io_getevents    => ret=100
io_destroy      => ret=0
```

Comment: Can you share the code so that I can learn from it?

Comment: Thanks, so what does `create a context to process 32 concurrent requests with io_setup` mean? does it means if I submit 320 requests, the kernel only process 32 requests at once, so the kernel needs to iterate 10 times to finish all requests?

Comment: And if I do `io_getevents` when the kernel iterate 2 times, then 64 is returned, if I wait enough when the kernel finished all requests, then 320 is returned?

Comment: Yes  `io_setup` defines the number of concurrent requests but I don''t know if the kernel has to iterate as parallelism is involved. In my code `io_getevents` waits for all `io_submit` requests to complete but you can change that.

Comment: Do you know why it stuck at
 `
./a.out 32 127
open            => fd=3
io_setup        => nr_iosetup=32 ret=0
io_submit       => nr_iosubmit=127 ret=126` ?

seems submit cannot be greater than 126

Comment: I have the same issue but I don't know why.